# Subasta de unas zapatillas, no me sirve el ciclo/bucle do...while

Tags: javascript, bucles

Se me está apareciendo este error cuando trato de hacer un bucle con Do..While.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: respuesta1 is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.sumar

El bucle ni siquiera me sirve y no sé en qué estoy fallando

```js
let sumar = () => {
  do {
       let respuesta1 = prompt("Cuánto ofreces?")

       if (respuesta1 < 10000 ) {
           respuesta1 = prompt("Puedes pushear más?")
       } 
       else if(10000 <= respuesta1 <= 15000){
           respuesta1 = prompt("Te sumamos unos accesorios si ofreces más")
       } 
       else{
                alert("vuelve a intentarlo!")
       }
    
    } while (respuesta1 != 15000  );

    alert("Aceptamos tu oferta!")
}

$(document).ready( () => {
  const boton1 = document.querySelectorAll(".card__boton1");
        boton1[0].addEventListener("click", sumar);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="card__boton1">push</button>
```

Comment: Saludos. Sugerencia 1: Finaliza todas tus sentencias bien (*punto y coma* donde va según sintaxis). Sugerencia 2: En *vuelve a intentarlo* me parece puede generar error ya que esta entre paréntesis. Sugerencia 3: Verifica actualmente exista el elemento **6**; es decir, que tengas al meno 7 botones en tu interfaz.

Comment: como respuesta1 esta definida dentro del while, el while no la ve.. y ahi esta tu error...

Comment: ademas.. esto if(10000 <= respuesta1 <= 15000){ no funciona como vos pensas... en programacion cada comparacion va por separado... por lo menos en js, no podes comparar asi los 3 valores....

Comment: Aparte de lo que te han indicado, el último else no está bien escrito. Debería ser algo como esto ` } else { respuesta1 = prompt("Vuelve a intentarlo"); }`

Comment: Modifique lo menos posible para que el codigo corra en pantalla, tenes varios errores que podes modificar, entre ellos esperar que el documento este cargado para poder levantar los botones.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que declarar `respuesta1` fuera del loop, y además tener en cuenta que no puedes declarar el intervalo como en matemáticas:

```
let respuesta1 = prompt("Cuánto ofreces?");
do {
if (respuesta1 < 10000 ) {
console.log(respuesta1);
    respuesta1 = prompt("Puedes pushear más?")
} else if(10000 <= respuesta1 && respuesta1 <= 15000){
console.log(respuesta1);
    respuesta1 = prompt("Te sumamos unos accesorios si ofreces más")
} else ("vuelve a intentarlo!")
} while (respuesta1 != 15000  );
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el feedback! me ayudó mucho!